# GridBagLayout Constraints not being respected once one of the JPanel has Content added to it

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, boxlayout

Trying to figure out how to keep the size ratio between these two panels 3:1.

What is looks like when I simply add the two JPanels to the GridBagLayout with the right constraints:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6TLR.png]

And this is what the code looks like:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    MainPanel() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        constraints.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        constraints.weightx = 3;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        JPanel pane1 = new JPanel();
        pane1.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        add(pane1, constraints);

        constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        constraints.gridx = 3;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        JPanel pane2 = new JPanel();
        pane2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        add(new RightPanel(), constraints);
    }
}
```

But then, once I start adding things like JButtons or JLabels in the right Panel, the 3:1 ratio is completely forgotten and the right Panel seems to take an arbitrary amount of space, no matter how small I make the objects inside of it.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/njYnw.png]

And this is what the code looks like:

```
class RightPanel extends JPanel {

    class ComboPanel extends JPanel {

        ComboPanel(String labelText) {
            JTextField textField = new JTextField();

            textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
            add(new JLabel(labelText));
            add(textField);

        }
    }

    RightPanel() {

        Box componentBox = Box.createVerticalBox();


        add(componentBox);

        JLabel currentPosX = new JLabel("Current X position: ( X )");
        currentPosX.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        JLabel currentPosY = new JLabel("Current Y position: ( Y )");
        currentPosY.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        Box positionBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

        positionBox.add(currentPosX);
        positionBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        positionBox.add(currentPosY);
        positionBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));
        positionBox.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        positionBox.setOpaque(true);

        componentBox.add(positionBox);

        componentBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));

        ComboPanel comboPanelX = new ComboPanel("Target X Position: ");
        comboPanelX.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        componentBox.add(comboPanelX);

        componentBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));

        ComboPanel comboPanelY = new ComboPanel("Target Y Position: ");
        comboPanelY.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        componentBox.add(comboPanelY);

        componentBox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));

        JButton commandButton = new JButton("Move");
        commandButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        componentBox.add(commandButton);

    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to add stuff to the JPanel on the right without screwing up the size ratio between the two main Panels.

Comment: GridBagConstraints cannot guarantee that one component is three times the width of another.  weightx and weighty determine how *extra space* is distributed; that is, the space beyond the preferred width/height of each component.  To keep a constant size ratio, you can use a [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html), but be warned, it can be tricky to use.

Comment: Didn't even consider SpringLayout. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: I can suggest you to use MigLayout. I have been using it by myself for many years, it's awesome. GridBagLayout is very hard to use.